# Can tonal languages be understood when whispered?

Tags: tonal-languages

I was wondering recently whether the tonal information is lost in tonal languages like Chinese, when it is whispered. Can Chinese still be understood when whispered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whispering changes the phonation, but not pitch of speech so I don't see any reason why tonal languages (with the possible exception of so-called register tones, which are really differences of phonation) would be any more affected than non-tonal ones